# Javascript innerHTML not allowing onClick on javascript function

Tags: javascript, onclick, href

I am not sure why, but the following

```
href='javascript:"+ openextlink('http://www.ipetfindr.com/shop/product/' + item._id.$id);+"'
```

seems to run automatically without the user clicking.

```
 document.getElementById("shop-items").innerHTML += "<div class='product " + cssclass + "'><div class='product-images-smaller'><span class='shop-large-image'><img src='" + item.pictures[0] + "'/></span></div><h1>" + item.name + "</h1><div class='prodtext'><b>Status:</b> " + item.status + "<br><b>Price:</b> $" + item.price + "<br><a id='shop_" + item._id.$id + "' href='javascript:"+ openextlink('http://www.ipetfindr.com/shop/product/' + item._id.$id);+"'><h3 id='dshop_" + item._id.$id + "' class='green_button'>Buy Now</h3></a></div></div>";
```

could anyone please tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

href=`'javascript:"`+ openextlink('http://www.ipetfindr.com/shop/product/'

I see a double quote , is it a typo, change to

href=`'javascript:'`+ openextlink('http://www.ipetfindr.com/shop/product/'